# How to serve versionned static content with nginx?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, build

I have a React application that is built statically and served by Nginx.

I serve the different version of the application with these 2 location context :

- This one serves the latest version of the application

```
location / {
    root /etc/application_development/latest;
    index index.html;
  }
```

- This one serves the different versions of the application

```
location /version {
    root /etc/kosmikpwa_development/$1;
    index index.html;
  }
```

It works fine but when an application is on `/version`, it tries to access its assets on `/static` instead on `/version/X.X.X/static`

How can I change that in order for the applications on `/version` to work as expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versioned builds, before building the app, in `package.json` of your react app, you need to set `homepage` like this:

```
"homepage": "version"
```

After this change, do not forget to append `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to the assets you use from your `public` folder if there exists one. So, these assets will be bundled according to your `homepage` defined in `package.json`.

Comment: What's the difference betweem homepage and PUBLIC_URL ?

Comment: This solution only works if your project is created by `create-react-app`. create-react-app sets `PUBLIC_URL` to `homepage`. In this case, there is no difference between them. Please see [this link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/d960b9e38c062584ff6cfb1a70e1512509a966e7/packages/react-scripts/config/paths.js#L26). Is your app created by `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes it is, but I build my application with `PUBLIC_URL=xxxx npm run build` so it's not different from setting the homepage in package.json to xxxx right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In fact, I think it is better to set `PUBLIC_URL=xxxx npm run build` :)